# PhoneGap Build 3.4.0 icon issue on uploading with iOS

Tags: ios, phonegap-build

I've done this before without issue with another app, and the development version works fine on an iPhone 4, iPhone 5S and an iPad Mini all running the latest version of iOS7. I'm using the same set-up as for the other app but for this one but I get this error:

**ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFiles':'icon.png'" at SoftwareAssests/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPAckage)**

This error is repeated once in Application Loader.

My icon.png is in the root folder, as it should be (I understand) and this the relevant bit of my config.xml:

```
<!-- Icons -->
    <!-- Android -->
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <!-- iOS -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="img/ios/icon/icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="img/ios/icon/icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="img/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="img/ios/icon/icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="img/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="img/ios/icon/icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="img/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="img/ios/icon/icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="img/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />

    <!-- Splash Screens -->
    <!-- Android -->
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />
    <!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
    <gap:splash src="img/ios/splash/Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="img/ios/splash/Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
    <!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
    <gap:splash src="img/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="img/ios/splash/Default-Portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="img/ios/splash/Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
    <!-- Retina iPad -->
    <gap:splash src="img/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <gap:splash src="img/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />
```

I added an extra icon.png in img/ios/icons just to test things, because that's what works for iOS6 and because there is no other "pure" icon.png in the img/ios/icons folder. It shouldn't need it though as the default 
    
in the root folder should work.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. It's not (afaik) the "proper" way to do it - my version should work - but it was given to me by a PGB employee.

I added

```
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
```

I'm posting this because until the PGB iOS icon issue is fixed (and many people are having the same) this will be invaluable.

And when the issue is fixed it will be obsolete. Such is life.